# Can you move your No Claims Bonus between EU countries?

Tags: eu, car-insurance

If you have insurance on a car in most of the EU countries your insurance premium is usually reduced for each year where you don't cause an accident. Insurance companies are usually accepting other companies' no claims bonus certificate if you switch the provider in a country.

Would it also be possible to move your NCB between providers inside the EU?

If yes, how, and what papers do I need to get from my current insurance provider?

Comment: Two general points: the old insurer often won't give a certificate of NCD until you cancel your policy with them. You may have to get a 30 day bridging policy, with no NCD, until you can get the documents to the new insurer. Secondly, the new insurer will probably only accept an NCD certificate in its own language. I your old insurer won’t give that, professional translation costs about Eur 70

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible since I have done it… but I am not sure if there is any specific EU-wide rule or standard document for that and I am not able to provide anything more than an anecdote.

IIRC, I phoned my soon-to-be insurer (in the Netherlands) to ask if they would consider it and then sent some document provided by my previous insurer (not even sure if it was translated) and it somehow worked out. If my recollection is correct, it was simply the document you get when switching insurers within my previous country of residence, nothing more complex than that.

Differences between insurers can also be quite significant, both in terms of basis premium and the way they handle any no-claim bonus, so it might be useful to inquire before signing up. People don't switch between banks or insurers often, so that new customers are especially valuable for these businesses. I don't know how much leeway individual customer reps have but as someone who has just moved in and is willing to become a customer, you might have some leverage.

Comment: I've heard this from my German friend, and he said that they've had to sue the insurance company (because some weird EU rule), but after that they accepted the NCB letter. But other than a few anecdotes, forum posts and pages on *some* insurance companies (here in the UK) that they explicitly allow it I couldn't really find anything definitive.

Comment: Also I'm more concerned that my old insurer in Hungary won't be able to supply me with a proper certificate.

Answer (score 5):

I've done it both from the UK to Germany, and from Germany to the UK. Which was a bit complicated because no-claims bonus is calculated differently in both countries. I don't remember the details of how it worked, but two insurance companies supplied me with the details that were accepted in the other country.

Comment: Could you tell me which insurance company transferred the ncd from Germany to UK?

Comment: I was not aware of any differnt calulcation. When I transferred from VGH (Germany) to Insure2Go (UK) last year, the only roblem I had was that the UK company insisted on an English language version of my current NC certificate. If VGH had not provided one, a prefessionl translation woudl have cost Eur 70 (and they don't let you tranlsate it yourself)

Answer (score 1):

The insurance company is not obliged to accept a foreign no-claims certificate, but they may do so to get your custom. It's more usual for companies that work in both countries. But make sure you get it clear before you commit yourself. Don't believe a verbal assurance that they will refund you money later after they have examined the no-claims certificate. They will not, in my experience.

Comment: Can you tell us which company reneged on such a verbal promise?